# How to get data from the Cardano blockchain using SQL queries?

Tags: query

I found the following screenshot where someone uses SQL to query the Cardano blockchain.
What is this tool called?

https://ipfs.blockfrost.dev/ipfs/QmTNaaR38P19rDfA1SuEN1h4wmcDNMoLg5pZdPxVyX42YG

---

Side note: The image is linked to an NFT: https://pool.pm/af52014edb909c70f34ef19fe96ba59142007a4c5e8a4cc9ff0b1c37.AdamWasHere

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The tool in question is [cardano-db-sync](https://github.com/input-output-hk/cardano-db-sync/).